# Get All Possible Available Currencies

Tags: java

I would like to get all possible available currencies.

Java 7 had provided such feature.

```
public static Set<java.util.Currency> java.util.Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()
```

However, I am still using Java 6 for development and deployment. May I know how I can get all possible available currencies? Code example are most welcomed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After studying the ISO table and the Currency class documentation, it seems that you can ask for currency as code or as Locale; and the class Locale has a `getAvailableLocales()` method.

So, the code would be:

```
    public static Set<Currency> getAllCurrencies()
    {
        Set<Currency> toret = new HashSet<Currency>();
        Locale[] locs = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

        for(Locale loc : locs) {
            try {
                Currency currency = Currency.getInstance( loc );

                if ( currency != null ) {
                    toret.add( currency );
                }
            } catch(Exception exc)
            {
                // Locale not found
            }
        }

        return toret;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have a question. I wrote this code, everything works fine but I can't find the Currency AFN from Afghanistan, the problem is only with me? Do you have any advise for me? Thank you

Comment: I am using now the joda-money library, that fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend testing that `Currency.getInstance(Locale locale)` doesn't return `null` before adding the result to your set. From the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)): "The method returns null for territories that don't have a currency, such as Antarctica."

Comment: For me, everything is going into the catch block..for all the locales..  with 2 types of errors: `Unsupported ISO 3166 country` and `java.util.Currency is not Comparable`

Answer (score 14):

This may be helpful for those who want to get it as a Java enumeration

```
    public enum Currency {
    AED("AED"), AFN("AFN"), ALL("ALL"), AMD("AMD"), ANG("ANG"), AOA("AOA"), ARS("ARS"), AUD("AUD"), AWG("AWG"), AZN("AZN"), BAM("BAM"), BBD("BBD"),
    BDT("BDT"), BGN("BGN"), BHD("BHD"), BIF("BIF"), BMD("BMD"), BND("BND"), BOB("BOB"), BOV("BOV"), BRL("BRL"), BSD("BSD"), BTN("BTN"), BWP("BWP"),
    BYN("BYN"), BYR("BYR"), BZD("BZD"), CAD("CAD"), CDF("CDF"), CHE("CHE"), CHF("CHF"), CHW("CHW"), CLF("CLF"), CLP("CLP"), CNY("CNY"), COP("COP"),
    COU("COU"), CRC("CRC"), CUC("CUC"), CUP("CUP"), CVE("CVE"), CZK("CZK"), DJF("DJF"), DKK("DKK"), DOP("DOP"), DZD("DZD"), EGP("EGP"), ERN("ERN"),
    ETB("ETB"), EUR("EUR"), FJD("FJD"), FKP("FKP"), GBP("GBP"), GEL("GEL"), GHS("GHS"), GIP("GIP"), GMD("GMD"), GNF("GNF"), GTQ("GTQ"), GYD("GYD"),
    HKD("HKD"), HNL("HNL"), HRK("HRK"), HTG("HTG"), HUF("HUF"), IDR("IDR"), ILS("ILS"), INR("INR"), IQD("IQD"), IRR("IRR"), ISK("ISK"), JMD("JMD"),
    JOD("JOD"), JPY("JPY"), KES("KES"), KGS("KGS"), KHR("KHR"), KMF("KMF"), KPW("KPW"), KRW("KRW"), KWD("KWD"), KYD("KYD"), KZT("KZT"), LAK("LAK"),
    LBP("LBP"), LKR("LKR"), LRD("LRD"), LSL("LSL"), LYD("LYD"), MAD("MAD"), MDL("MDL"), MGA("MGA"), MKD("MKD"), MMK("MMK"), MNT("MNT"), MOP("MOP"),
    MRO("MRO"), MUR("MUR"), MVR("MVR"), MWK("MWK"), MXN("MXN"), MXV("MXV"), MYR("MYR"), MZN("MZN"), NAD("NAD"), NGN("NGN"), NIO("NIO"), NOK("NOK"),
    NPR("NPR"), NZD("NZD"), OMR("OMR"), PAB("PAB"), PEN("PEN"), PGK("PGK"), PHP("PHP"), PKR("PKR"), PLN("PLN"), PYG("PYG"), QAR("QAR"), RON("RON"),
    RSD("RSD"), RUB("RUB"), RWF("RWF"), SAR("SAR"), SBD("SBD"), SCR("SCR"), SDG("SDG"), SEK("SEK"), SGD("SGD"), SHP("SHP"), SLL("SLL"), SOS("SOS"),
    SRD("SRD"), SSP("SSP"), STD("STD"), SYP("SYP"), SZL("SZL"), THB("THB"), TJS("TJS"), TMT("TMT"), TND("TND"), TOP("TOP"), TRY("TRY"), TTD("TTD"),
    TWD("TWD"), TZS("TZS"), UAH("UAH"), UGX("UGX"), USD("USD"), USN("USN"), UYI("UYI"), UYU("UYU"), UZS("UZS"), VEF("VEF"), VND("VND"), VUV("VUV"),
    WST("WST"), XAF("XAF"), XAG("XAG"), XAU("XAU"), XBA("XBA"), XBB("XBB"), XBC("XBC"), XBD("XBD"), XCD("XCD"), XDR("XDR"), XFU("XFU"), XOF("XOF"),
    XPD("XPD"), XPF("XPF"), XPT("XPT"), XSU("XSU"), XTS("XTS"), XUA("XUA"), XXX("XXX"), YER("YER"), ZAR("ZAR"), ZMW("ZMW");

    private String iso4217Code = "";

    Currency(String code) {
        this.iso4217Code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return iso4217Code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Combine the [ISO 4217](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/currency_codes.htm) ([xml](http://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/table_a1.xml)) definition with your requirements and the sample from openJDK7 if you want **all** Currencies. If you iterate over the default Locales you only get 78 of 180 defined by ISO 4217.

```
String[] viaLocales = { "JPY", "CNY", "SDG", "RON", "MKD", "MXN", "CAD",
    "ZAR", "AUD", "NOK", "ILS", "ISK", "SYP", "LYD", "UYU", "YER", "CSD",
    "EEK", "THB", "IDR", "LBP", "AED", "BOB", "QAR", "BHD", "HNL", "HRK",
    "COP", "ALL", "DKK", "MYR", "SEK", "RSD", "BGN", "DOP", "KRW", "LVL",
    "VEF", "CZK", "TND", "KWD", "VND", "JOD", "NZD", "PAB", "CLP", "PEN",
    "GBP", "DZD", "CHF", "RUB", "UAH", "ARS", "SAR", "EGP", "INR", "PYG",
    "TWD", "TRY", "BAM", "OMR", "SGD", "MAD", "BYR", "NIO", "HKD", "LTL",
    "SKK", "GTQ", "BRL", "EUR", "HUF", "IQD", "CRC", "PHP", "SVC", "PLN",
    "USD" };
String[] iso4217WithoutViaLocales = { "XBB", "XBC", "XBD", "UGX", "MOP",
    "SHP", "TTD", "UYI", "KGS", "DJF", "BTN", "XBA", "HTG", "BBD", "XAU",
    "FKP", "MWK", "PGK", "XCD", "COU", "RWF", "NGN", "BSD", "XTS", "TMT",
    "GEL", "VUV", "FJD", "MVR", "AZN", "MNT", "MGA", "WST", "KMF", "GNF",
    "SBD", "BDT", "MMK", "TJS", "CVE", "MDL", "KES", "SRD", "LRD", "MUR",
    "CDF", "BMD", "USN", "CUP", "USS", "GMD", "UZS", "CUC", "ZMK", "NPR",
    "NAD", "LAK", "SZL", "XDR", "BND", "TZS", "MXV", "LSL", "KYD", "LKR",
    "ANG", "PKR", "SLL", "SCR", "GHS", "ERN", "BOV", "GIP", "IRR", "XPT",
    "BWP", "XFU", "CLF", "ETB", "STD", "XXX", "XPD", "AMD", "XPF", "JMD",
    "MRO", "BIF", "CHW", "ZWL", "AWG", "MZN", "CHE", "XOF", "KZT", "BZD",
    "XAG", "KHR", "XAF", "GYD", "AFN", "SOS", "TOP", "AOA", "KPW" };
```

Answer (score 4):

I have been using Baltasarq's answer and I find it slows down my app due to a number of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException's being thrown, which is no fault of his, but actually the author of the Currency library, who has elected to throw an exception as opposed to an error ([Raw Code](https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jre_emul/android/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Currency.java)).

However looking into that Library, there is a public static method `getAvailableCurrencies` which will give you all the available currencies as a set without having to loop through all the available locales and throw a bunch of exceptions.

The revised code now looks like this:

```
public static Set<Currency> getAllCurrencies() {
    Set<Currency> currencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
    return currencies;
}
```

Which of course, is silly, you can just as well use the Currency's own static method and save yourself an unnecessary method call. #SaveTheStack

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise a version a little better of Baltasarq code to avoid duplication:

```
    ArrayList<String> currencys = new ArrayList<String>();
    Locale[] locs = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

    for(Locale loc : locs) {
        try {
            String val=Currency.getInstance(loc).getCurrencyCode();
            if(!currencys.contains(val))
                currencys.add(val);
        } catch(Exception exc)
        {
            // Locale not found
        }
        Collections.sort(currencys);
    }
```

I have tested on android.

Comment: Baltasarq's answer avoids duplication by using a set, which overwrites entries when they already exist. Also, he uses a `HashSet`, which is also typically faster than running `contains(...)` in an array list.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the library `nv-i18n` available on maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
    <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
    <version>1.22</version>
</dependency>
```

To see all currency codes with it, you just have to use:

```
for (CurrencyCode code : CurrencyCode.values()) {
    System.out.format("[%s] %03d %s\n", code, code.getNumeric(), code.getName());
}
```

You can see more details about this class and library here:
http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-i18n/

Answer (score 1):

Use [JodaMoney](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/index.html). Inside joda-money.jar I find MoneyData.csv It has all ISO 4217 currencies. Use **org.joda.money.CurrencyUnit** to pull currencies.

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<CurrencyUnit> currencyUnits = CurrencyUnit.registeredCurrencies();


    for (CurrencyUnit currencyUnit : currencyUnits) {
        System.out.println(
                currencyUnit.getCode() +" " + 
                currencyUnit.getNumericCode() + " "+
                currencyUnit.getNumeric3Code()+ " "+
                currencyUnit.getCountryCodes());
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Currency java class but I was not able to find the Currency of Afghanistan (AFN), so I was not sure if I could rely on this `Currency Library`. To fix this I am using the `joda-money` library.

So I put in my `pom.xml` this:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
    <version>0.11</version>
</dependency>`

And in my code I use this:

`List<CurrencyUnit> currencyUnits = CurrencyUnit.registeredCurrencies();`

to get all Currencies, and the AFN was there so I am using this library now.

I hope it can help.