# XPAges get the Curency Code List

Tags: dialog, xpages, currency

In an edit box when you specify that it is a currency there is a dropdown list to select the currency code. In the app I'm working on I have an edit box for the user to enter the local currency. I would like to give them a dialog with the same list in it. 
Can we access the same list that the editBox gets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if it will result in the same list that Designer uses, but it looks like you can get the list of currencies Java knows about by using the technique from the answer in [Get All Possible Available Currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536968/get-all-possible-available-currencies)